# Помогите разобратся с ajax скриптом

Tags: php, html, ajax

Решил прикрутить к сайту обновление контента, без перезагрузки страницы, 
ниже приведён код файла: search_inlist.php:

```js
function sctop() {
    $('body,html').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 800);
    return false;
};
   
$('#btn1').live('click', function(){     
    $("#results").ajaxStart(function(){ 
        sctop();  
        NProgress.start();
        //$('#results').fadeOut("slow");
        $('#preloader').attr('id', 'preloaderno');
        return false; 
    });
    $("#results").ajaxComplete(function(){
        //$('#results').fadeIn("slow");
        $('#preloaderno').attr('id', 'preloader');
        return false; 
    });

    var params = $(this).attr('href').split('?');
  
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'http://site.com/core/search_inlist.php',
        data: params[1]+'&cattitle_nc=<?=$cattitle_nc?>&cityforcat=<?=$cityforcat?>',
        success: function(data) {
            $('#results').html(data);
        }
    });

    return false; 
});  
   
NProgress.done();
```

```html
<div id="preloader" class="text-center">Идёт загрузка...<br><img src="http://site.com/images/loading.gif"></div>
<div id="results">
здесь прописан код обращения к базе и сюда же выводит результат ajax 
</div>
```

Суть его такова, при клике по номеру страницы(пагинация), включается прокрутка вверх, передает данные по которым вытягивает записи из базы и отображает их, проблема в том что когда я дохожу допустим до 7 страницы начинаются глюки, идет scrollTop подгужаются данные, но колесиком мышки опустится обратно вниз не могу, что самое главное этот глюк наростает с каждой страницы, сначала немного нужно подождать и колесико на прокрутку вниз срабатывает, при клике на следующую страницу еще больше глючит, но подождав все таки срабатывает прокрутка вниз с помощью мишки, а вот уже на седьмой клик по странице все подвисает и ужасно тормозит, перечитал много, понять не могу почему, так как не хватает ума.

**Обновление**

Вот сама кнопка

```
if($total_rows>=$lp){
    $a="<a id=\"btn1\" href=\"".$h."?op=search";
    if(@$data_from_pag!="")$a.="&amp;query=".@$data_from_pag;
    if(@$_GET['l'])$a.="&amp;l=".$_GET['l'];
    if(@$_GET['nomorph'])$a.="&amp;nomorph=".@$_GET['nomorph'];
    if(@$_GET['cat'])$a.="&amp;cat=".@$_GET['cat'];
    if(@$_GET['type'])$a.="&amp;type=".@$_GET['type'];
    if(@$_GET['images'])$a.="&amp;images=".@$_GET['images'];
    if(@$_GET['city'])$a.="&amp;city=".@$_GET['city'];
    if(@$_GET['from'])$a.="&amp;from=".@$_GET['from'];
    if(@$_GET['before'])$a.="&amp;before=".@$_GET['before'];
    if(@$_GET['time'])$a.="&amp;time=".@$_GET['time'];
    $a.="&amp;page=";
    if($page!=1)$pervpage=$a."1\" title=\"".$lang[174]."\">&nbsp;&nbsp;&#171;&nbsp;&nbsp;</a> ";
    if($page!=$total)$nextpage=$a.$total."\" title=\"".$lang[175]."\">&nbsp;&nbsp;&#187;&nbsp;&nbsp;</a>";      
    $pageleft="";$pageright="";
    for($i=$c['limit_pagination_on_page'];$i>=1;$i--)if($page-$i>0)$pageleft.=$a.($page-$i)."\">".($page-$i)."</a>";
    for($i=1;$i<=$c['limit_pagination_on_page'];$i++)if($page+$i<=$total)$pageright.=$a.($page+$i)."\">".($page+$i)."</a>"; 
    echo "<ul class=\"pagination\"><li>".@$pervpage.@$pageleft."<span class=\"active_page\">".$page."</span>".@$pageright.@$nextpage."</li></ul>";

}}
```

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я не вижу причин выводить скролирование к верху в отдельную функцию.

У вас идет привязка события клика к одной единственной кнопке? Тогда о какой пагинации идет речь? К слову ID-шник должен быть одним единственным и уникальным на всю страницу, выдавать одинаковые ID разным элементам запрещается.

Почему бы Вам не проверить свою функцию Ajax без всякого лишнего мусора и уже потом навешивать доп.функционал? Уберите прелоадер, уберите изменение id(опять же зачем Вы меняете Id? у элемента #preloader).

```
$('#btn1').live('click', function(){      
    $('body,html').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 800);

    var params = $(this).attr('href').split('?');

    $.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      url: 'http://site.com/core/search_inlist.php',
      data: params[1]+'&cattitle_nc=<?=$cattitle_nc?>&cityforcat=<?=$cityforcat?>',
      success: function(data) {
        $('#results').html(data);
      }
    });
    return false; 
});
```

Ко всему прочему, совершенно неясно как отрабатывает запросы сервер, поэтому сказать что-то более конкретно нельзя, Ваш пример не является достаточным для диагностики на стороне. Ведь вполне возможно, дело в серверной стороне.